# SqlAlchemy Informix Status

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, informix

Can anyone advise the status of the Sql-Alchemy project for Informix?
I am relatively new to Python.  I have worked with Dbi and SQL-Alchemy for postgres and made both of those work.

I have spend many hours trying to make Informix work.  I find the instructions on GitHub for sql-alchemy difficult to follow and I am put off by the comment that says it not yet "ready".

I have made the IfxPy module work and I have also made IfxPyDbi work.  I would be happy to work with IFxPyDbi if the execute method returned a dictionary (like IfxPy.fetch_assoc) but I can only make it return tuples.

Does anyone have any advice about the best approach to start working on a python project with Informix.  What is the best place to start?  Am I on the right track with these modules?  Am I missing something on SQL-Alchemy for Informix?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Infomix Python driver (IfxPy and IfxPyDbi) is reasonably well tested and Informix team is happy to help you if you face problem. At the same time the Python SQL Alchemy adapter for Informix database it is work in progress and not ready for use; we still need to complete the metadata mapping for the Informix database to produce right output. Unfortunately, we don’t have an ETA yet for this task.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That's exactly what I needed.  Now I know the direction to head off in.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that I’ve found reasonable success using the windows 64-bit informix odbc driver, and pyodbc.
Python 3.8, informix 12.

A bit of advice getting it into a data frame.
`pd.DataFrame.from_records()` is your friend.